# MongoDB distinct occurance | Map-Reduce word count

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query

I have a collection and its documents look like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("45854464646544")
    "ip" : "1.1.1.2",
    "ts" : ISODate("2017-07-31T01:24:15.961Z"),
    "id" : NumberLong(12345)
}
```

I'm trying to get the occurance of `ip` and its count. So the expected output is:

```
{ "_id" : "1.1.1.1", "value" : 130 }
{ "_id" : "10.1.10.1", "value" : 37 }
```

I'm trying the following to syntax to get my expected output:

```
var map = function() {  
    var summary = this.ip;
    if (summary) { 
        for (var i = summary.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (summary[i])  {      
               emit(summary[i], 1); 
            }
        }
    }
};

var r = function( key, values ) {    
    return values.length;
};

db.com.newzsocial.analytics.LinkRedirectLog.mapReduce(m, r, { out: {merge: "word_count"}, query: {"id" : {$in : [NumberLong(68075115),NumberLong(68075115),]}, "ts" : {$gte: ISODate("2017-07-31T00:00:00.000Z"), $lte : ISODate("2017-08-06T23:59:59.000Z")}}})
```

The output i'm getting is close but not correct:

```
{
        "result" : "word_count",
        "timeMillis" : 8424,
        "counts" : {
                "input" : 1243,
                "emit" : 16269,
                "reduce" : 150,
                "output" : 17
        },
        "ok" : 1
}

{ "_id" : ".", "value" : 130 }
{ "_id" : "0", "value" : 37 }
{ "_id" : "1", "value" : 120 }
```

input:1243 is correct. Instead of ip, i feel its picking something else. Please help.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Is is "count the distinct occurrence of each IP address matched by the query"?

Comment: Yes, trying to get the occurrence of distinct ip address and not the distinct count.

Answer (score 0):

Worked by modifying the mapper code as:

```
var map = function() {  
    var summary = this.ip;
    if (summary) { 
        emit(summary, 1); 
    }
};
```